# ¿Com hacer un Update con condicionales que hacen referencia a otra tabla?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Os planeo mi problema. Tengo una tabla en la que quiero transformar ciertos registros en NULL. No quiero modificar todos los registros de mi tabla, así que necesito aplicar condicionales con la clausula **WHERE**. Os expongo la solución que he intentado, la cual empieza a correr pero de momento ninguna de las dos se ha completado. Decir que las dos tablas que uso están indexadas correctamente.

Método:

```
UPDATE tabla1 c
        SET sAct = null
    FROM tabla1 a
    LEFT JOIN tabla2 b  on a.id_x=b.id_x and a.id_y=b.id_y
        where b.cca='15' and c.sAct is not null and c.p>0;
```

He probado de hacerlo en forma de subquery pero en principio entiendo que debería tardar incluso más.

Alguna idea? Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si solo quieres actualizar los registros de `tabla1` que tienen una relación con los de `tabla2` donde los `id_X` e `id_y` sean coincidentes, para los registros de `tabla_2` que tengan un valor '15' y en `tabla_a` para la columna `sAct` tuvieran algún contenido y en la columna `p` tengan un valor superior a `0`

```
UPDATE tabla1 a
        SET a.sAct = null
    FROM tabla2 b  
Where a.id_x=b.id_x 
      And a.id_y=b.id_y
      And b.cca='15' 
      And A.sAct is not null 
      And a.p>0;
```

Comment: al hacerlo así, me da un error de que la tabla "a" no existe como que no detecta el alias de la tabla1

Comment: La falta de práctica con `postgreSql`. Ya he editado la respuesta. [Update join postgreSql] (https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-update-join/)

Comment: ahora si, supongo que al evitar el join ahora va mucho más rapido, gracias :)